# Bootstrap cards not showing like in examples

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-cards

Why do my Bootstrap cards look weird? In the examples they look like cards with a border and white padding but mine look like text only without the padding and the white background.

For example:

[image: Bootstrap card rendering example]

I don't know if the code will help you but here it is:

```css
.container {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -340px;
  text-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.themdfactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/card1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">This is Card #1</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you are looking at the wrong documentation ...verify your versions. This is how it looks on v4. http://www.bootply.com/FaH0rKmUgg and the same code on v3 doesn't works http://www.bootply.com/2ofIwquKgf

Comment: thank you using v4 worked but it still looks a bit weird do you know how i can center it and it shows in the navbar instead in the middle? do i have to put the position:absolute?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It shows up fine by me. You have to make sure that you are linking the version 4 style sheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: You are using position absolute in your container for no reason. Remove the css properties you added to the container. If you want to center the card you need to do two things. Set a width to the card for example: 300px and then add a class with margin: 0 auto; display: block; and use it in your card wrapper.

Comment: Additionally, if you are just referencing bootstrap 4 for the card css you should use the one in bootstrap 3, which is already referenced in your index. It is called thumbnail: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content

Answer (score 34):

The [Bootstrap 4 card](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/) feature has undergone additional changes from the earlier v4-alpha version(s) to the v4-beta version. However, the examples on the Bootstrap web site still use the older class name. The cards still render, but the padding is lost if the older class name is used.

Current (September 2017) example using the `card-body` class ([CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38622102/2074605) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38620737/2074605).

Comment: This in combination with the bootstrap v4 answer, should be the exact answer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: Find / replace of `card-block` to `card-body` fixed all my padding issues in Bootstrap v4.0.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Copying card css from the boostrap4 version into your bootstrap3 solution worked for me. Nice if you are stuck on bootstrap3.

Just drop the following in your CSS anywhere.

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-block {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-title {
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.card-subtitle {
    margin-top: -0.375rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-text:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card-link + .card-link {
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
}

.card > .list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card > .list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.card-header {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.card-header:first-child {
    border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}

.card-footer {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    background-color: #f7f7f9;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.card-footer:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-header-tabs {
    margin-right: -0.625rem;
    margin-bottom: -0.75rem;
    margin-left: -0.625rem;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.card-header-pills {
    margin-right: -0.625rem;
    margin-left: -0.625rem;
}

.card-primary {
    background-color: #0275d8;
    border-color: #0275d8;
}

.card-primary .card-header,
.card-primary .card-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.card-success {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.card-success .card-header,
.card-success .card-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.card-info {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
    border-color: #5bc0de;
}

.card-info .card-header,
.card-info .card-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.card-warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
    border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.card-warning .card-header,
.card-warning .card-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.card-danger {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d9534f;
}

.card-danger .card-header,
.card-danger .card-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.card-outline-primary {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #0275d8;
}

.card-outline-secondary {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ccc;
}

.card-outline-info {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #5bc0de;
}

.card-outline-success {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #5cb85c;
}

.card-outline-warning {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.card-outline-danger {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #d9534f;
}

.card-inverse {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}

.card-inverse .card-header,
.card-inverse .card-footer {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.card-inverse .card-header,
.card-inverse .card-footer,
.card-inverse .card-title,
.card-inverse .card-blockquote {
    color: #fff;
}

.card-inverse .card-link,
.card-inverse .card-text,
.card-inverse .card-subtitle,
.card-inverse .card-blockquote .blockquote-footer {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}

.card-inverse .card-link:focus, .card-inverse .card-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.card-blockquote {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
}

.card-img {
    border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-img-top {
    border-top-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
    border-top-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-img-bottom {
    border-bottom-right-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
    border-bottom-left-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-deck {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .card-deck .card {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1 0 0%;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
        flex: 1 0 0%;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .card-deck .card:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .card-deck .card:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-group {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .card-group .card {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1 0 0%;
        -ms-flex: 1 0 0%;
        flex: 1 0 0%;
    }
    .card-group .card + .card {
        margin-left: 0;
        border-left: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:first-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:first-child .card-img-top {
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:first-child .card-img-bottom {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:last-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:last-child .card-img-top {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:last-child .card-img-bottom {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .card-group .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .card-img-top,
    .card-group .card:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .card-img-bottom {
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        column-gap: 1.25rem;
    }
    .card-columns .card {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L4055

Answer (score 1):

This might be old, but are you using a customized bootstrap file by any chance? I recently was trying to work with cards using our customized file, and the same thing was happening to me. Then I realized that there are no card classes in the bootstrap file, nor is there any mention of Cards on the customize page.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Seems strange to me, I even had a coworker verify it though. Hope this helps.

Comment: hey cymbal-table i'm  using bootstrap cdn :). thanks for asking though but i have fixed the problem long ago :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed bootstrap via a package manager, such as NPM:

For some package managers, the default installed version is `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2` which doesn't appear to have this feature.

This could be misleading as the correct version is described on Bootstrap's Getting started > Download section, [found here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers)

To resolve, ensure you are referencing the latest package version `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`