# What is the '.well' equivalent class in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

In bootstrap-3 there is [`.well`](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_wells.asp) class which adds a rounded border around an element with a gray background color and some padding.

```
<div class="well">Basic Well</div>
```

But, I didn't find any `.well` class in bootstrap-4. Is there any tag equivalent to `.well` in bootstrap-4?

Comment: `well` has been dropped entirely for the new card component. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Answer (score 264, accepted):

**Update 2018...**

`card` has replaced the `well`.

**Bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="card card-body bg-light">
     Well
</div>
```

***or***, as two DIVs...

```
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

(Note: in Bootstrap 4 Alpha, these were known as `card-block` instead of `card-body` and `bg-faded` instead of `bg-light`)

http://codeply.com/go/rW2d0qxx08

Answer (score 42):

Wells are dropped from Bootstrap with the [version 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/).

You can use [Cards](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/) instead of Wells.

Here is a quick example for how to use new Cards feature:

```
<div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h3 class="card-title">Card Title</h3>
    <p class="card-text">This text will be written on a grey background inside a Card.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">This is a Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

This worked best for me:

```
<div class="card bg-light p-3">
 <p class="mb-0">Some text here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers seemed to work well with buttons. Bootstrap v4.1.1

```
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Save
        </button>
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary">
            Cancel
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So true!I can confirm that you need the separate card-body class attached to its own div to make buttons appear normally!

Answer (score 2):

Sure [officially version](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) says the cards are the new replacements for Bootstrap wells. But Cards are a quite broad Bootstrap components now. In simple terms, you can also use [Bootstrap Jumbotron](https://www.tutorialmines.net/bootstrap-jumbotron/) too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a one line option:

```
    <div class="jumbotron bg-dark"> got a team? </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/

Comment: Starting from bootstrap 5.0, the jumbotron class has been removed. Here are examples to build a jumbotron like component in bootstrap 4.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/jumbotron/

Answer (score 0):

I'm mading my classes well for class alert, for me it looks like it's getting nice, but some tweaks are sometimes needed as to put the width 100%

```
<div class="alert alert-light" style="width:100%;">
  <strong>Heads up!</strong> This <a href="#" class="alert-link">alert needs your attention</a>, but it's not super important.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Card seems to be "discarded" LOL, I found the "well" not working with bootstrap 4.3.1 and jQuery v3.4.1, just working fine with bootstrap 4.3.1 and jQuery **v3.3.1**. Hope it helps.