# How to Place Image Grid into Bootstrap Card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I have a Bootstrap Card with a picture below.
Instead of a single picture, I want to insert a picture grid. How would I conduct this? Trying to combine creates misaligned design with white space

**Bootstrap Card Code:**

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Grid Image Code:**

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/san-fransisco-768x432.jpg" alt="san francisco">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/london-768x432.jpg" alt="london">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/new-york-768x432.jpg" alt="new york">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="cape town">
</div>

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 0em;
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**Trying to combine creates misaligned design with white space:**

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/san-fransisco-768x432.jpg" alt="san francisco">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/london-768x432.jpg" alt="london">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/new-york-768x432.jpg" alt="new york">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="cape town">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Using MVC Net Core

Other resources learning:
[Bootstrap cards not showing like in examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930480/bootstrap-cards-not-showing-like-in-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your solution.

```css
.card {
  width:18rem;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    margin:auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto; /* The grid-template-columns property specifies the number (and the widths) of columns in a grid layout. */
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/san-fransisco-768x432.jpg" alt="san francisco">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/london-768x432.jpg" alt="london">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/new-york-768x432.jpg" alt="new york">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="cape town">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
img {
  width: 49%;
}
```

Or its better to add custom CSS class to all images inside card and give its `width: 49%`

[codepen working demo](https://codepen.io/nitinnairdev/pen/xopeBa)

Comment: I am using mvc core, not working here, how does 49% make sense? seem like its tweaking margins, etc

Comment: I am going to have a multitude of pictures, sizes, text, so looking for solution which works always

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195736/discussion-between-nitin9nair-and-tom85morris).

Answer (score 0):

Change the columns widths from `100px` to `1fr` and it works regardless of the width of the `.card`

```css
.card {
  width:18rem;
  background: pink;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/san-fransisco-768x432.jpg" alt="san francisco">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/london-768x432.jpg" alt="london">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/new-york-768x432.jpg" alt="new york">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="cape town">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, what is the grid-container margin auto property? I am looking through here, dont see it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid_Container,  do you have any reference book? trying to learn, thanks

Comment: That's not necessary. it was left over from something i was testing.